# How to remove item from list in VUE?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the container which consist of different `div`. I want to remove specific ones on click. My code (by example from vue page) not working and I cant figure why... May be there is some suggestions?

```
<div class="m-t-15">
    <div v-for="(tag, index) in $parent.post.tags" v-on:remove="$parent.post.tags.splice(index, 1)" class="btn-group btn-group-sm m-b-5">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled">@{{ tag.name }}</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" v-on:click="$emit('remove')">
            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
        </button>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: If the list of items is in a parent component, you need to handle the array manipulation there, not in the child component.

Comment: @Phil the real problem is that the `emit` not working...

Comment: Show us the corresponding code ('remove' listener)...

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't need to access parent's data like that. Mutating parent's data is not a good practice. Just pass props down, and emit event back to the parent component.

Child components emit `remove` event:

```
<button @click="$emit('remove', i)">...</button>
```

The parent component:

```
<child :list="list" @remove="remove"></child>

remove (i) {
  this.list.splice(i, 1)
}
```

Please see the working example here: http://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/PmYNBb?editors=1010